# How to configure jetty to request client certificate for specified resources?

Tags: ssl, jetty, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

sslConfig:

```
<New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
    <Set name="KeyStorePath">../conf/jetty/etc/keystore</Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePassword">secretpass</Set>
    <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">test</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePath">../conf/jetty/etc/truststore</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePassword">secretpass</Set>
    <Set name="EndpointIdentificationAlgorithm"></Set>
    <Set name="NeedClientAuth">true</Set>
    <Set name="WantClientAuth">true</Set>
</New>
```

Setting NeedClientAuth to true requires client to provide certificate for all resources. But in my case I want to request certificate only for specified resources.

For example I need to request certificate for /resource1/*
And use just HTTPS for /resource2/*

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, as the SSL/TLS negotiation step occurs way before the request is actually made.

No web server can apply different SSL/TLS rules based on the resource being requested, as the information present in the http request hasn't even been sent yet at the time of the SSL/TLS negotiation.

If this is important, set up 2 different ServerConnectors, on different ports.

1. ServerConnector with Client Auth - the `/resource1/*` content is served from here
2. ServerConnector without Client Auth - all other web resources that don't need the client auth requirement (and doesn't even have the `/resource1/*` content)